# Is it possible to make the following example fully polymorphic in F#?

Tags: f#

```
type Mul = Mul with member inline __.Op(a: ^a,b: ^a) = a*b
type Div = Div with member inline __.Op(a: ^a,b: ^a) = a/b
type Add = Add with member inline __.Op(a: ^a,b: ^a) = a+b
type Sub = Sub with member inline __.Op(a: ^a,b: ^a) = a-b

let inline op x a b =
    (^a: (member Op: ^b * ^b -> ^b) x,a,b)

let inline tup2 a b c d = op Mul a b, op Mul c d
let inline tup2' f a b c d = op f a b, op f c d

let a = tup2 1 2 3.0f 4.0f
//let b = tup2' Mul 1 2 3.0f 4.0f //Gives a type error.
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make the types do what I want in the example above or if I have finally reached the limitation of F#'s type system. Actually, there is a way to make the above work and that is to put all the types into one DU and then pattern match on the DU type like the following:

```
type Operation = 
    | Mul 
    | Add
    | Sub
    | Div
    member inline t.Op a b = 
        match t with 
        | Mul -> a * b
        | Add -> a + b
        | Sub -> a - b
        | Div -> a / b
let inline map' (f: Operation) a b c d =
    (f.Op a b, f.Op c d)
map' Mul 1 2 3.0f 4.0f
```

But assuming the first example worked, it would be a more dynamic solution. It is a pity something like passing a higher order function by name inside an argument and having it inlined on the spot to make it generic is not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This limitation of most modern type systems is well explained in kvb's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213599/generic-higher-order-function/).

Here's a workaround, based on the hack suggested there. In fact it's very similar to your code but less verbose.

```
type Mul = Mul with static member inline ($) (Mul, a: ^a) = fun (b: ^a) -> a*b
type Div = Div with static member inline ($) (Div, a: ^a) = fun (b: ^a) -> a/b
type Add = Add with static member inline ($) (Add, a: ^a) = fun (b: ^a) -> a+b
type Sub = Sub with static member inline ($) (Sub, a: ^a) = fun (b: ^a) -> a-b

let inline tup2' f a b c d = (f $ a) b, (f $ c) d

let b = tup2' Mul 1 2 3.0f 4.0f
```

The idea is that instead of defining a function you define a type with a single method (which you already did) in this case it will be an operator which would mean apply.

So instead of doing `f x` you will write `f $ x`.

**UPDATE**

As said before, your code is not far from the solution suggested in that answer.
Here's a working example which is even closer to your original code:

```
type Mul = Mul with static member inline Op(Mul, a: ^a,b: ^a) = a*b
type Div = Div with static member inline Op(Div, a: ^a,b: ^a) = a/b
type Add = Add with static member inline Op(Add, a: ^a,b: ^a) = a+b
type Sub = Sub with static member inline Op(Sub, a: ^a,b: ^a) = a-b

let inline op x a b = ((^a or ^b): (static member Op: ^a * ^b  * ^b -> ^b) (x, a, b))

let inline tup2 a b c d = op Mul a b, op Mul c d
let inline tup2' f a b c d = op f a b, op f c d

let a = tup2 1 2 3.0f 4.0f
let b = tup2' Mul 1 2 3.0f 4.0f //Gives NO type error.
```

So that's basically your original code but using static methods and using an `or` in the constraints. By doing this the compiler doesn't solve the constraint early and so it works.

I used the operator because it's less verbose and in this case I like how it reads, since Haskell `$` means function application.

Comment: This is interesting, but even now that I know how to do it, I can't figure out why simply calling the function with an inlined helper does not work. I tried adapting your example, but I am still not sure. Is there something special about the way the compiler tries to resolve operators? If I define it as `let inline op x a = x $ a` it works, but if I do something like `let inline op x a = (^a: (static member ($): ^a * ^b -> ^c) x,a)` I can't get it to work at all.

Comment: @Gustavo : Are you saying the space is significant? (The only difference I see is the space in `x,a`.)

Comment: @Gustavo He was asking about your comment to me which you forgot to modify. 'Your constraint is not 100% the same, it should be `let inline op x a = (^a: (static member ($): ^a * ^b -> ^c) x, a)`' I am guessing you meant to write 'Your constraint is not 100% the same, it should be `let inline op x a = ((^a or ^b): (static member ($): ^a * ^b -> ^c) x, a)`'

Comment: MarkoGrdinic, @ildjarn My mistake. That's exactly what I meant. Sorry about the confusion I created, I will delete that comment to reduce the noise.