# Type inference not working when passing map function

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, f#, type-inference

First of all; thank you for taking the time to read my question. If there is any more information you need or would like me to change something please let me know.

When I pass in an array handler function the type inference does not work, but when I add the function to the module instead of injecting it then it does work.

Tried adding type annotation but that's just ignored and F# warns about code being less generic when calling it the first time and then errors out with wrong type the second time.

But if I change:

```
let handleAction
  //following does not work, comment out next line
  (mapItems : 'a -> 'b [] -> int -> ('b -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b [])
```

to

```
let handleAction
  //following does not work, comment out next line
  (notPassed : 'a -> 'b [] -> int -> ('b -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b [])
```

Then it works just fine. Trying to remove upwards dependencies but can't get F# to understand the type.

```
let mapItems
  action
  state 
  index
  handlerfn =
    state
      |> Array.indexed
      |> Array.map (
        fun (i, item) ->
          if index < 0 then
            handlerfn item action
          else if i = index then
            handlerfn item action
          else
            item)

//Mediator calling the handler for the action
let handleAction
  //following does not work, comment out next line
  (mapItems : 'a -> 'b [] -> int -> ('b -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b [])
  //notPassedIn //uncomment this and it works 
                //even though mapItems here and mapItems
                //passed in are the exact same code
  state
  action =
    match action with
    |Pausable action -> //actions specific to pausable stopwatch
        let handler = 
          mapItems
            action //warning: less generic
            state
            action.index
        match action.``type`` with
          //... pausable actions (added to support pause/continue)
    | StopWatch action -> //actions from stop watch
        let handler = 
          mapItems
            action//error: wrong type
            state
            action.index
        match action.``type`` with
          //...handling stopwatch actions
```

Full code is here:
https://github.com/amsterdamharu/programmingbook/tree/example8

```
(*
  stopwatch module
*)
//types
type SWActionType =
  | Start          of int
type StopWatchAction = {
  ``type``:SWActionType
  //there may be more than one stopwatch in the application
  index:int
}
type StartDate =
  | NoStartDate
  | Date of int
type SingleStopWatchState = {
  status:string
}
type StopWatchState = SingleStopWatchState []
//handlers for the stopwatch actions
let handleStart current state =
  {state with status = "started"}
//mediator for stopwatch
let StopWatchHandleAction 
  mapItems
  (state:StopWatchState)
  (action:StopWatchAction) =
    let handler = 
      mapItems
        action
        state
        action.index
    match action.``type`` with
      | Start current ->
          handler//call handler with state
            (fun
              (state:SingleStopWatchState)
              (action:StopWatchAction) ->
                (handleStart current state))
(*
  Pausable stopwatch that extends stopwatch and supports
  pause action
*)
type PActionType =
  | Pause          of int
type PausableStopWatchAction = {
  ``type``:PActionType
  index:int
}
type PAction =
  | StopWatch of StopWatchAction
  | Pausable of PausableStopWatchAction
type SinglePausableStopWatchState = {
  status:string
  isPaused:bool
}
type PausableStopWatchState = SinglePausableStopWatchState []
//handlers for pausable stopwatch
let handlePause current (state:SinglePausableStopWatchState) =
  {state with 
    status = "paused"
    isPaused = true
  }
//mediator for pausable stopwatch
let PausableHandleAction
  (mapItems : 'a -> 'b [] -> int -> ('b -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b [])
  state
  action =
    match action with
    |Pausable action -> //actions specific to pausable stopwatch
        let handler = 
          mapItems
            //warning:This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type 'PausableStopWatchAction'.
            action
            state
            action.index
        match action.``type`` with
          | Pause current ->
              handler//call handler with state
                (fun
                  state
                  action ->
                    (handlePause current state))
    | StopWatch action -> //actions from stop watch
        let handler = 
          mapItems
            (*
              ERROR
              This expression was expected to have type
              'PausableStopWatchAction'    
              but here has type
              'StopWatchAction'
            *)
            action
            state
            action.index
        match action.``type`` with
          | Start current ->
              handler//call handler with state
                (fun
                  state
                  action -> //would use some of stopwatch handlers here
                    {state with
                      status ="started"
                    })
(*
  Application consuming stopwatch and pausable
*)
type ApplicationState = {
  stopwatch:StopWatchState
  pausablestopwatch:PausableStopWatchState
}
type Action =
  | StopWatch of StopWatchAction
  | PausableStopWatch of PAction
let ArrayHandler
  action
  state 
  index
  handlerfn =
    state
      |> Array.indexed
      |> Array.map (
        fun (i, item) ->
          if index < 0 then
            handlerfn item action
          else if i = index then
            handlerfn item action
          else
            item)
//application mediator:
let handleAction 
  (state : ApplicationState)
  action =
  match action with
    | StopWatch
        action ->
          {state with//return application state
            //set the stopwatch state with updated state
            //  provided by the mediator in stop watch
            stopwatch = 
              StopWatchHandleAction
                ArrayHandler state.stopwatch action}
    | PausableStopWatch 
        action ->
          {state with//return application state
            pausablestopwatch = 
              PausableHandleAction
                ArrayHandler state.pausablestopwatch action}
```

Comment: I'm failing to understand or reproduce the problem. Can you edit this to a smaller example that still illustrates the problem without any dependencies on other code? Also, please copy out the full warnings and errors that you refer to.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Thank you for your reply, I have added code to reproduce. Could use more minimal code but am afraid if I do so I'll get an answer that does not apply to my situation but answers the example I provided.

Comment: @HMR there is another general solution not listed in the answer. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213599/generic-higher-order-function/7224269#7224269

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function genericity is part of the function declaration. When you pass a function as a value, its genericity is lost.

Consider the following minimal repro:

```
let mkList x = [x]
let mkTwo (f: 'a -> 'a list) = (f 42), (f "abc")
let two = mkTwo mkList
```

This program will cause the same warning and same error you're getting. This is because, when I say `f: 'a -> 'a list`, the type variable `'a` is a property of `mkTwo`, not property of `f`. We could make this clearer by declaring it explicitly:

```
let mkTwo<'a> (f: 'a -> 'a list) = (f 42), (f "abc")
```

This means that, on every given execution of `mkTwo`, there has to be only *one* `'a`. The `'a` cannot change during an `mkTwo` execution.

This has an implication for type inference: the first time the compiler comes across the expression `f 42`, it thinks "*hey, `f` is called with an `int` argument here, so `'a` must be `int`*" - and issues you a helpful warning saying "*look, you say this should be generic, but you're actually using it with a concrete type `int`. This construct makes this function less generic than declared*".

Then, the compiler comes across the expression `f "abc"`. Since the compiler has already decided that `'a = int`, and therefore `f : int -> int list`, it complains that `string` is the wrong parameter type.

In your original code, the function is `mapItems`, and you're calling it with two different types of arguments: the first time with `PausableStopWatchAction` (and get a warning), and the second time with `StopWatchAction` (and get an error).

There are two general solutions to this problem:

### General solution 1: pass the function twice

```
let mkList x = [x]
let mkTwo f g = (f 42), (g "abc")
let two = mkTwo mkList mkList
```

Here, I pass the exact same function `mkList` both times. In each case the function loses genericity, but it loses it *in two different ways*: the first time it becomes `int -> int list`, and the second time it becomes `string -> string list`. This way, `mkTwo` sees it as two different functions, of different types, and so can apply it to different arguments.

### General solution 2: use an interface

Interface methods, unlike functions, do not lose genericity when the interface is passed as argument. So you can wrap your `mapItems` function in an interface and use it:

```
type MkList =
    abstract member mkList : 'a -> 'a list

let mkList = { new MkList with member this.mkList x = [x] }
let mkTwo (f: MkList) = (f.mkList 42), (f.mkList "abc")
let two = mkTwo mkList
```

This is admittedly more bulky than pure functional code, but it gets the job done.

### Specific solution for your code

But in your specific case, that is all not even required, because you could "bake" the `action` right into `handlerfn`
(here I assume that you're actually using `action` inside `handlerfn`, even though the code you posted doesn't show that):

```
let mapItems
  state 
  index
  handlerfn =
    state
      |> Array.indexed
      |> Array.map (
        fun (i, item) ->
          if index < 0 then
            handlerfn item 
          else if i = index then
            handlerfn item 
          else
            item)

...

let handleAction
  (mapItems : 'a [] -> int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a [])
  state
  action =
    match action with
    |Pausable action -> //actions specific to pausable stopwatch
        let handler = 
          mapItems
            state
            action.index
        match action.``type`` with
         | Pause current ->
             handler//call handler with state
               (fun state ->
                     (handlePause current state))
    | StopWatch action -> //actions from stop watch
       let handler = 
         mapItems
           state
           action.index
       match action.``type`` with
         | Start current ->
             handler//call handler with state
               (fun state ->
                   //would use some of stopwatch handlers here
                   {state with
                     status ="started"
                   })
```