# Passing generic function as a parameter

Tags: generics, f#, f#-4.1

I've been trying to learn F# lately and coming from object-oriented background, I have a little problems understanding generics in this one case.

Let's say I have the following functions:

```ml
let genericFunction<'a> (x: 'a) =
    ()

let myFunction (fn: ('a -> unit)) =
    fn 2
    fn 2UL

let test =
    myFunction genericFunction
```

As a C# developer I'd expect `fn` to be a generic function, which can take any argument. But the `fn 2` call constraints the generic parameter `'a` to `int` and thus it cannot be called with `uint64`.

Why the generic type is constrained? How one would implement this without passing in two functions?

The compiler warns about the constraining and finally errors:

```
source_file.fs(5,8): warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type 'int'.

source_file.fs(6,8): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int    
but here has type
    uint64
```

Here's the error:
http://rextester.com/RRRWTR28520

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567508/180286

Comment: Thanks! Good answer, exactly what I was looking for, but with wrong search terms.

Comment: @jani Have a look at this answer as well, which is older and has another approach plus some more information about the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213599/generic-higher-order-function/7224269#7224269

Comment: @Gustavo Thanks for the link. I have to take another look at the magic tomorrow with fresh eyes. Sadly the link to the gist (n-uples) in your answer is dead, any chance reviving it?

Comment: @Jani I fixed the broken link.