# Deconstructing Discriminated Unions

Tags: f#

I have a discriminated-union type of the form

```
type ParameterName = string
type ParameterValues =
    | String of string[]
    | Float of float[]
    | Int of int[]
type Parameter = Parameter of ParameterName * ParameterValues
```

I want to pass the ParameterValues part to a function taking generic arguments returning unit, such as

```
let func1 (name:string) (data:'a) = printfn "%s" name
```

To deconstruct `Parameter` I could wrap `func1` like this

```
let func2 (Parameter (name, values)) =
    match values with
        | String s -> func1 name s
        | Float s -> func1 name s
        | Int s -> func1 name s
```

however this is inconvenient if I have to do this for multiple functions. Instead, I would like to define a more flexible wrapper like this:

```
let func3 (fn: ('a -> 'b -> unit)) (Parameter (name, values)) =
    match values with
        | String s -> fn name s
        | Float s -> fn name s
        | Int s -> fn name s
```

This however fails, as the type of `b` gets restricted to `string[]` in the first option of the match expression; consequently the match expression fails with the error `Type string does not match type float.`

Is this expected? How can I work around this problem?

Comment: Yes it is expected, F# does not support higher-ranked polymorphism. You could change the type of `data` to `obj`.

Comment: In addtion to @Tomas answer you can also receive three times the same function: ``let func3 fn1 fn2 fn3 (Parameter (name, values))`` otherwise there is [another compile-time solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213599/generic-higher-order-function/7224269#7224269)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour. The problem is that you cannot directly pass a generic function as an argument to another function in F#. When you define a function as follows:

```
let func3 (fn: ('a -> 'b -> unit)) (Parameter (name, values)) = (...)
```

... you are defining a generic function `func3` that has two generic parameters and, when those are specified, can be called with a given function and a parameter. This can be written as:

```
\forall 'a, 'b . (('a -> 'b -> unit) -> Parameter -> unit)
```

What you would need to do is to make those type parameters not top-level, but make the first parameter itself a generic function. You could write this as:

```
(\forall 'a, 'b . ('a -> 'b -> unit)) -> Parameter -> unit
```

This can be clumsily written in F# using interfaces:

```
type IFunction<'a> =
  abstract Invoke<'b> : 'a -> 'b -> unit

let func1 = 
  { new IFunction<string> with
    member x.Invoke<'b> name (data:'b) = printfn "%s" name }

let func3 (fn: IFunction<string>) (Parameter (name, values)) =
    match values with
    | String s -> fn.Invoke name s
    | Float s -> fn.Invoke name s
    | Int s -> fn.Invoke name s
```

In practice, your function does not really need to be generic, because you are never using the second argument - but you could probably achieve pretty much anything that you can achieve with this interfaces trick just by passing the data as `obj` and your code would be significantly simpler than this monstrosity!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm very new to F# so it's a bit above my head, but I think I understood the `obj` idea. Could you take a look at my answer and tell me if that's what you had in mind?

Comment: @sebhofer Yep, your `obj` implementation is what I had in mind! +1 to your answer from me! (it's always tricky to answer these kinds of questions - people coming from Haskell would complain that my answer was too non-technical and others would find it pretty challenging; glad you find a solution that works for you though!)

Comment: My comment was certainly not meant as a criticism, I like that you explained some of the background. It's just that to understand your example code I would have to read up on interfaces now, and I have the feeling there are other aspects of F# I should learn first.

Comment: One more quick question: The way I understand the solution using `obj` right now is that it effectively disables type checking as everything is an `obj` (I'm not sure if this is a technically correct way to say this, but I hope you get the gist). Is this correct? If so this is probably considered a "hack", right?

Comment: @sebhofer Yes, that's correct - I would not say it's a hack if you are not doing anything unsafe with the `obj` value afterwards - if you just want to print it, that's perfectly fine, because you can safely print any objects. If you wanted to do more, then it depends on what exactly...

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestions by Lee and Tomas, I came up with the following solution:

```
type Parameter = Parameter of string * obj

let func0 (name:string) (data:obj) = printfn "%s %A" name data

let func1 (fn: string->obj->unit) (Parameter (name, value)) =
    fn name value

let p1 = Parameter ("p1", [|"a"; "b"|])
let p2 = Parameter ("p1", [|1.; 2.|])

func1 func0 p1
func1 func0 p2
```

Comment: well, it can be simplify a bit

Comment: `let func0 = printfn "%s %A"`

Comment: @FoggyFinder Well, `func0` is not really the function I will be using if that wasn't clear...